# $V$ is a linear space. Need to compute $T^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Given: $V$ is a linear space $(\dim V = n)$ and there is a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ that $T^n = 0$ and $T^{n-1} \ne 0$ , also there's $u \in V$ that $T^{n-1}(u) \ne 0$
>
> Prove that $B = (u,T(u),T^2(u),\dots,T^{n-1}(u))$ is a base for V.

Well, I tried saying that there are scalars $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ and:

$a_0u + a_1T(u) + ... + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(u) = 0$
, So if I prove that $a_0=a_1=a_{n-1}$ = 0 then I can say because there are n elements and also it's linearly independent. Thus, B is a base.

Well, I tried using the function $T^{n-1} ,T^{n-2},...,T^0$ like that:

[Explanation]:
First, I use the function $T^{n-1}$ on $a_0u + a_1T(u) + ... + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(u) = 0$

which means it will look like this:  $a_0T^{n-1}u + a_1T^n(u) = 0$

(Because, all the other elements will have a dimension higher than $DimV = n$ so I erased them)

But, $T^n = 0$ Thus,  $a_0T^{n-1}u = 0$ , From here I say $T^{n-1} \ne 0$ So $a_0 = 0$.

Now I use $a_0 = 0$ and I use the function $T^{n-2}$ on $ a_1T(u) + ... + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(u) = 0$ And so on.. Until I get all the scalars equal to zero. Then, I can say it is a base.

What do you guys think? Is my explanation correct?

Comment: Seems ok to me.

Comment: @Hippalectryon Great, Thanks! :) , I know that my explanation is bad but I think it's understandable.

Comment: you do not have to write **also there's $u\in V$ that $T^{n-1}(u)\neq 0$**..

Comment: I see, @PraphullaKoushik Thx.

Comment: I do not understand second line of your last paragraph... do you mind to make it more precise?? I can see that you understand how to do but then there are some gaps as i have said...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I've edited.

Comment: This looks better now :) well done as of now! But then  i guess you have only said that they are linearly independent but have you shown they span whole $V$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I don't need to. I know that $DimV = n$ and there are n vectors in the base, So it's enough to prove that they are linearly independent.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS : that is it !!!! well done!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

[The answer]:
First, I use the function $T^{n-1}$ on $a_0u + a_1T(u) + ... + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(u) = 0$

which means it will look like this:  $a_0T^{n-1}u + a_1T^n(u) = 0$

(Because, all the other elements will have a dimension higher than $DimV = n$ so I erased them)

But, $T^n = 0$ Thus,  $a_0T^{n-1}u = 0$ , From here I say $T^{n-1} \ne 0$ So $a_0 = 0$.

Now I use $a_0 = 0$ and I use the function $T^{n-2}$ on $ a_1T(u) + ... + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(u) = 0$ And so on.. Until I get all the scalars equal to zero. Then, I can say it is a base.

Comment: This solution actually says something more general. Namely that if $T$ is an endomorphism with $T^m=0$ and $T^{m-1}\neq 0$, then there is a $u\in V$ such that $(u, Tu, T^2u, \ldots, T^{m-1}u)$ is linearly independent. This imposes no relations on $m$ and the dimension of $V$ ($V$ can even be infinite dimensional).